# Node.js hosted on firebase : update database with key stored in a variable

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am bumping against a very interesting design decision, I would like to update a given entry in the database of form: https://imgur.com/QBLMIkU

So far I have something like:

```
update(id : string, key : string, val : string ) : void {

        const dbRef = firebaseAdmin.database().ref('datasets');
        const entry = dbRef.child(id)

    entry.once('value', snap => {

        let content = snap.val()

        if ( content && content[key] ){

            entry.update({ key : val })
        } 

    })

}

@use case: update('-LDc9Wa4Wj1wzEx5CsKN', 'content' 'new content loresum')
```

The key line is: `entry.update({ key : val })`, instead of overwriting `content` field, the code is creating a new entry with key `key` and value `val`. How can I update the `content` field only w/o rewriting the whole data entry?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, it's that a new entry with a key of "key" is being written which has the value of the val parameter. In that case:

```
let newData = {};
newData[key] = val;
entry.update(newData);
```

Basically, your `entry.update({ key : val })` is saying "Update the record with key value of 'key' and make it equal the passed in val parameter". Since that key doesn't exist in your data, it creates a new key value pair which equals "key: my New Value"

Comment: @|Ty| if I do that then I have to recreate all the old database entries for `id`, which is something I was hoping to avoid. If there is a way to pass in the variable key so that the key in the JSON take the value of the variable it would be great